# How do I keep my home directory clean?

Tags: linux, home-directory

I have far too much in my home directory, but I can't move a lot of it because it's mostly dotfiles that are required by other programs (games, libraries, etc.). Ideally, everything of that sort would just stay in ~/.config.

My ideal solution is something like:

- If an application is not on a whitelist, and it tries to write to `~`, redirect it to `~/.config` before giving up.
- If an application tries to read from a file in `~` and it's not there, check in `~/.config` too before giving up.

However, I can't imagine how that could work without breaking everything horribly, unless I was going to write a custom filesystem driver or something. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /etc/inputrc
```

Add:

```
set match-hidden-files off
```

This will do it for all users.  To do it just for your user, add the above line to ~/.inputrc

See the [Readline Init File Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html) in the BASH Reference Manual.

Comment: The OP was complaining of Tab Completion being a pain in the comments.  This option disallows dot files in Tab Completion

Comment: Read [this forum post](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-631205-start-0.html), which was the issue the OP was describing in the comments that have disappeared.  Those comments are the reason I answered in the way I did.